# How to get travis-ci to respect .Rbuildignore when building R package?

Tags: r, github, package, travis-ci

I've hooked up a [github repo](https://github.com/davebraze/FDButils) containing an R package to Travis CI and the package seems to build fine. But, when travis builds it on github the contents of the .Rbuildignore file are not respected. How can I fix that? I've read through travis docs and don't find anything helpful.

What's mostly at issue is the contents of a \doc\ folder, holding a pkgdown site. For obvious reasons, I don't want that included in the source package.

The exclusion works fine when building the package locally, but I'm a travis novice and haven't been able figure out how to get it to cooperate. Here are the contents of my .travis.yml file:

```
language: R
r_packages:
  - car
  - ggplot2
sudo: false
cache: packages
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Don't know what the issue is but maybe try ^docs insteadl of ^docs$. I would also suggest switching to github actions instead of travis-ci, as most people have. Check out: https://github.com/r-lib/actions/. Setup is simple, it's literally copying and pasting some files.